# Is there a SQLDeveloper for Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

What is the recommended tool for developing against a Microsoft SQL Server database? We have a legacy Microsoft SQL Server that I'm developing new services for. I have never worked with Microsoft SQL Server before.

For example, for developing against Oracle databases, currently I use Oracle SQLDeveloper to figure out queries and explore indexes, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download **[Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)** to get started.

Choose the last *Download* button corresponding to `ENU\x86\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe`, if you only want the Management Studio.

Descriptions about the other executables are listed on the page.

Comment: +1 OMG, yes! Finally a standalone SSMS installer! I wonder if the "Express" (SSMS) version is still nerf'ed from the "Standard" version, though?

Comment: I couldn't find it when I looked a few months ago. Had to do an "instance install" to get it... :(

Answer (score 5):

Typically, you will use [SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx) or SSMS.  You can also use Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you, Cade. Both answers were the same and simultaneous. Hard to pick just one right answer...